# Oracle SQL: Insert failed ORA-01722: invalid number, Data is numeric not string, why'd it fail?

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader, ora-01722

I did a quick search and some have said this error is a result of trying to load numeric values that should be strings? I have no alpha characters. I will later be finding min/max/avg of all columns so I need them to be strings.

error:

> --Insert failed for rows  1  through  50 
>   --ORA-01722: invalid number
>   
>   1 row of 23 columns of data (0's included):
>
> 25:33.5   -   -   -   -   -   -   -1.23   6.56    6.93    0   -   -   -   -   -   998.26  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   183.2   2.35    -   840 -   -   -   -   -   -   1.56    -1.56   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   84.2    -   47.97   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0.81    0.48    -   -   -   -   -   0   11.37   4.5 -10.05  -   -   13.3

for columns:

```
INSERT INTO CAR_LOGS (DEVICE_TIME, GX, GY, GZ, G_CALIBRATE, BAROMETER, ENGINE_COOL, ENGINE_LOAD, ENGINE_RPM, FUEL_TRIM_BANK1_LONG, FUEL_TRIM_BANK1_SENSOR1, FUEL_TRIM_BANK1_SENSOR2, FUEL_TRIM_BANK1_SHORT, GPS_VS_OBD_SPEED_DIFF, AIR_INTAKE_TEMP, MASS_AIR_FLOW_RATE, O2_VOLTS_BANK1_SENSOR1, O2_VOLTS_BANK1_SENSOR2, SPEED, THROTTLE_POSITION, TIMING_ADVANCE, TURBO_BOOST_VACUUM_GUAGE, VOLTAGE) 
VALUES (27-Sep-2016 19:25:33.467,-1.23,6.56,6.93,-0.0,998.26,183.2,2.35,840.0,1.56,-1.56,0.0,0.0,0.0,84.2,47.97,0.81,0.48,0.0,11.37,4.5,-10.05,13.3);
```

I have like 8k rows of data in this file and it's failed of course on all of them. I'm fairly new to sql. My father is the db expert, I'm just learning programming at school/db on the side. Using Oracle SQL, I tried importing a csv file directly into the table and chose the columns correctly.

Also, I have like 20 files...any advice for a rookie on how to load them all the same way?

I found:

```
LOAD
  DATA 
cd path  
cat file*.csv > all_files.csv
  APPEND INTO TABLE TBL_DATA_FILE
    EVALUATE CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
    REENABLE DISABLED_CONSTRAINTS
    EXCEPTIONS EXCEPTION_TABLE
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  TRAILING NULLCOLS
  ( 
    COL0,
    COL1,
    COL2,
    COL3,
    COL4
  );
```

Do I replace path with

> C:\Users\c_thu\Desktop\Database\CarLogsSEPT.2016

or attach it directly after the word path?

Two questions I guess but I only really want to figure out this error. Second question is meh.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are putting time without `single` `quotes`. Try below.

```
 INSERT INTO CAR_LOGS (DEVICE_TIME,
                      GX,
                      GY,
                      GZ,
                      G_CALIBRATE,
                      BAROMETER,
                      ENGINE_COOL,
                      ENGINE_LOAD,
                      ENGINE_RPM,
                      FUEL_TRIM_BANK1_LONG,
                      FUEL_TRIM_BANK1_SENSOR1,
                      FUEL_TRIM_BANK1_SENSOR2,
                      FUEL_TRIM_BANK1_SHORT,
                      GPS_VS_OBD_SPEED_DIFF,
                      AIR_INTAKE_TEMP,
                      MASS_AIR_FLOW_RATE,
                      O2_VOLTS_BANK1_SENSOR1,
                      O2_VOLTS_BANK1_SENSOR2,
                      SPEED,
                      THROTTLE_POSITION,
                      TIMING_ADVANCE,
                      TURBO_BOOST_VACUUM_GUAGE,
                      VOLTAGE)
        VALUES (
                  TO_TIMESTAMP ('27-Sep-2016 19:25:33.467',
                                'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
                  -1.23,
                  6.56,
                  6.93,
                  -0.0,
                  998.26,
                  183.2,
                  2.35,
                  840.0,
                  1.56,
                  -1.56,
                  0.0,
                  0.0,
                  0.0,
                  84.2,
                  47.97,
                  0.81,
                  0.48,
                  0.0,
                  11.37,
                  4.5,
                  -10.05,
                  13.3);
```

Quick Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR_LOGS
(
   DEVICE_TIME   TIMESTAMP, --datatype of column has to be  timestamp to show milliseconds
   GX            NUMBER,
   GY            NUMBER,
   GZ            NUMBER
);
```

Record Insert;

```
INSERT INTO CAR_LOGS (DEVICE_TIME,
                      GX,
                      GY,
                      GZ)
        VALUES (
                  TO_TIMESTAMP ('27-Sep-2016 19:25:33.467',
                                'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
                  -1.23,
                  6.56,
                  6.93);
```

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Comment: I think I spoke too soon. I was not writing the code, I was simply clicking "add selected columns" on the import gui, after right-clicking the table. I copy&pasted the printout of the error, not the code. I get the same error after running the provided solution.

Comment: Check the datatype of the columns of your table. Are all the columns varchar or number. If all columns are varchar put a single quotes around all the figures. Also your column DEVICE_TIME must of datatype date to allow such inserts. Check out.

Answer (score 0):

Such error means you're trying to insert into numeric column value that cannot be converted to number. Can you please provide table description?
For sure please use 
`to_date('27-Sep-2016 19:25:33.467','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`
when inserting date instead of just posting 27-Sep-2016 19:25:33.467. 
You shouldn't insert date without specifying format in to_date function. You have an NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter which says what is format of the date during current session. But this parameter is session dependent so if you not use to_date your code can not work on other clients.

Comment: Please execute:
desc CAR_LOGS;
and post results.